# Turning to HDMI dongle for hdtv's

Tags: wifi, hdmi

is there any way to turn raspberry to a HDMI WiFi dongle for HDTV's with non-integrated WiFi support ... (things like chrome cast -Microsoft dongle -(Roku) - ...) 
can be any support for Wi-Di (wireless display)?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the [Kodi](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_on_Raspberry_Pi) distribution. I use it on my RaPi to run a projector.

It even receives the projector remote signals down the HDMI cable and responds correctly.

Downsides are a lack of codec support and lack of apps for things like Netflix. For a fully featured solution you might be better off getting a dedicated dongle or a pre-built Android box running Kodi.

Comment: There is a Netflix app for Kodi, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: There may well be a Netflix app for Kodi, but not Kodi on the RaPi. It's not considered a secure platform. The current 'workaround' still involves the paid-for PlayOn Media Server on your network.
[RaPi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=112921)
[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/2y8zf5/netflix_on_raspberry_pi/)
[Kodi Tutorial](http://mymediaexperience.com/raspberry-pi-xbmc-with-raspbmc/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure my Pi2 running OSMC Kodi has a netflix app so I can't tell you for sure since I don't own a Netflix subscription .
However, this is off-topic since there is no mention of Netflix in the question.

Comment: guys actually it cant handle more than 480p (even encoded ) i think its not the issue of the processor pf the raspberry beacuse most of the high_end router have the same cpu (there are mostly have the frequency of broadcom soc that integrated in raspberry) its the kodii thing ....